# How do you 'copyout' in Git

Tags: git, testing, version-control

I have cases where I need to `'copyout'` an older version (commit) of my code for side by side comparison with my current code.

The action needs to be more than simply swapping between branches, which does not provide concurrent access.

What are the good ways of doing a `copyout` of an old commit from Git so that I get an 'off-repo' copy of that old version?

Just to be clear: This is not a code review style comparison, but comparing the running software with all lights flashing, videos being played, user interactions etc. - hance the need for a full copy.

Comment: By "side by side comparison", you don't mean a simple `git diff commit-x commit-y` do you?

Comment: @DKinzer - sounds like a proper answer.

Comment: “so that I get an 'off-repo' copy of that old version?”

Sounds like his intention's were clear, and this isn't satisfied by a `git diff` (unless formatting a patch would suffice.

Answer (score 5):

The `git` distribution comes with a contributed script called `git-new-workdir`.
You would use it as follows:

```
git-new-workdir project-dir new-workdir branch
```

where project-dir is the name of the directory containing your `.git` repository.
This script avoids the *clone the entire repository* approach by setting up a few symlinks.

Comment: Just make sure you don't delete the wrong (e.g. master) working copy afterwards (if you didn't push everything somewhere else).

Comment: Unfortunately I get 'command not found' on my windows msysgit version 1.7.4

Comment: I've also just found this short explanatory thread http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/5/21/1900054/thread

Comment: And a CMD window version at https://github.com/joero74/git-new-workdir/blob/master/git-new-workdir.cmd

Comment: This sounds like a good option. You can also use --git-dir= to specify a git directory if you are outside of your repo.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of this. +1

Comment: The DOS CMD version needs Windows Vista(6) or Windows 7. It uses the new mklink command which gives the symlink capability.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do with this file but here are some things that might help you.

- If you simply want to compare files across branches, you can do a `git diff branch1:file branch2:file` to see their differences.
- If you want a physical copy of a file that's in the other branch, you can do `git cat-file -p otherbranch:file > tmp` to get it in `tmp`. You do what you want with it then.
- If you want to diff between commits, you can simply say `git diff treeish1 treeish2` to see the differences (where a [treeish](http://book.git-scm.com/4_git_treeishes.html) is a hash, branch, tag etc.).
- If you want a physical copy of the repository at the time of a commit completely so that you can take a look, you can do `git archive --format=tar treeish path | (mkdir /tmp/foo && cd /tmp/foo && tar xvf -)` to get an "exported" copy in /tmp/foo. This will not be a version controlled copy. Just a snapshot of the files at the commit pointed to by treeish.
- There's also the obvious way mentioned by [Beaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252929/how-do-you-copyout-in-git/6253023#6253023) which is to make two clones and use them.

Answer (score 3):

Philip, Git doesn't provide a good way to do this, I can only suggest you do the following; assuming "directory-a" is your working-copy.

```
cd directory-a
git status # make sure it's clean
cd ../
git clone directory-a directory-b
```

Then you'll have two copies of the repository (this is the recommended Git way) if a simple diff won't do.

You can then revert, merge, branch and mess with both individually without risk or detriment to the other. `directory-b` will contain a fresh working copy, taken from `directory-a`'s status, and won't know about `origin`, so it's really just a clone of `directory-a` with all history up to that point.

**Fun Fact:** Some SCM's don't support branching, this is how you branch in those systems.

Comment: Mercurial definitely supports branching.  http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/

Comment: @John edited my answer to remove the reference to Mercurial, it was off-topic, and not all that important, note was only intended for the OP to know that this isn't a "hack" but somehow a design philosophy that "repositories and branches should be cheap"

Comment: @Beaks: This one sure looks like it's probably the right one. The only concern would be the size of the .git sub-directory [with all history up to that point] [I'm in a windoze environment, the current mechanism has been to use Zips at key points in the development before the big-iron SCM kicks in]

Comment: @Philip, you can throw-away the cloned copy with no harm to your original in this scenario, and, to take care of hard dirk space, you could always force a git GC, and squash some ancient history  on the `source` repository before starting work (if the repository is so large, these actions might pay off regardless)

Comment: This is an obvious way that escaped me but it might be expensive if the `.git` directory is big. Also, multiple clones doesn't "feel" right to me after having used git for a while. I've put a link to your answer in mine and +1d yours.

Comment: @Philip, `git clone` is supposed to use hard links to save space with multiple clones on the same disk.  I'm not sure if or how well that holds true on Windows, though.

Comment: You don't get hard links with msysgit. It would take extra space.

Answer (score 0):

You can always clone the repository to another location, then rollback that copy of the repository.

You could also delete the files that make it a repository if you truly want it disconnected -- but I doubt you need to do that step.

Comment: If you want to "disconnect" it, you should use `git-archive`. It's the recommended way.